# TSQL - Dynamic Create Table and Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a bit of trouble dynamically creating a table and inserting into it.  I have tried this multiple ways and cannot produce a desirable outcome. See below for a simplified version of what I am trying to do. Note that this is only one attempt - I have tried others as well (such as `INSERT INTO [table] EXEC(@exe)`) with no success either.

Every time I attempt below, I get a message

> Command(s) completed successfully

but no table has even been created.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar

SET @sqlText = 
N'
IF OBJECT_ID(''[BudgetProcedures].dbo.UnitOccupancy'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [BudgetProcedures].dbo.UnitOccupancy;

CREATE TABLE [BudgetProcedures].dbo.UnitOccupancy (Property varchar(15)
                                                    ,Unit varchar(15)
                                                    ,YearLength varchar(15)
                                                    ,Lease varchar(15));

INSERT INTO [BudgetProcedures].[dbo].[UnitOccupancy] (Property, Unit, YearLength, Lease)

(SELECT ''ExProp''  
,''ExUnit''
,''ExYrlen''
,''ExLease''
)
'

EXEC(@sqlText)
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to use dynamic sql here but the problem is because you didn't specify the length for your variable. Whenever you are doing dynamic sql you should ALWAYS select it before executing it so you can see what you are actually executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare as:

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000)
```

Other way it has length 1 by default. And since you have new line in the beginning of statement it doesn't throw syntax exception(your query contains only new line symbol and it is legal). Delete new line and you will get an error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.

You can use:

```
print @sqlText
```

to see what does your statement look like.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation on this Giorgi.  I must also ask - are you aware of what to do when the variable exceeds the max length?  In my actual script (not posted due to length) nvarchar(max) fails because it does not capture the entire string.

Comment: @E.Monk, set @v = N'split' set @v = @v + N'it'

Comment: @E.Monk: the max length of a `nvarchar(max)` is **1 billion characters** - I can *hardly believe* that you truly exhausted that limit !!

Comment: @marc_s, while it is true for variables it is not true for string literals: `DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SET @A = REPLICATE('A',50000)
SELECT LEN(@A)` Output is 8000.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.  Giorgi is correct - I am getting a max of 8000 (which is too small).  However, even when I attempt to use Giorgi's recommendation of splitting it, I am still limited by 8000.  I will continue to fidget with this and keep you all updated as to what solution I find.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: that's because you're not explicitly casting the argument in the `REPLICATE` as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - read the docs! If you use `DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX); SET @A = REPLICATE(CAST(N'A' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 500000); SELECT LEN(@A)` - you get **a lot more** than 8000 characters!

Comment: @marc_s, you are absolutely correct. Better way is to cast to varchar(max)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to successfully test your script when I changed this:

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar
```

To this:

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :  instead of using a local variable and then executing it , you can straight away execute the query dynamically using exec statement as below :

EXEC ('IF OBJECT_ID(''[BudgetProcedures].dbo.UnitOccupancy'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [BudgetProcedures].dbo.UnitOccupancy;

CREATE TABLE [BudgetProcedures].dbo.UnitOccupancy (Property varchar(15)
                                                    ,Unit varchar(15)
                                                    ,YearLength varchar(15)
                                                    ,Lease varchar(15));

INSERT INTO [BudgetProcedures].[dbo].[UnitOccupancy] (Property, Unit, YearLength, Lease)
(SELECT ''ExProp''
,''ExUnit''
,''ExYrlen''
,''ExLease''
)')